# scrapy LOG_LEVEL setting in spider does not work

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to set the `LOG_LEVEL` setting in the `Spider` class?

When I tried to set it to `INFO`, I still see the `DEBUG` messages.

When I set it on the `settings.py` file or via the command line option `--loglevel`, it works.

I thought I could set any settings via the `custom_settings` attribute. Is that a bug? (Scrapy 1.0.3 and python 2.7.10)

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Test"
    ...
    custom_settings = {
        'LOG_LEVEL': 'INFO',
    }
```

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1612

Comment: Yes I created the github ticket after posting the message on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
from scrapy.log import ScrapyFileLogObserver
from scrapy import log


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "myspider"  

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        ScrapyFileLogObserver(open("spider.log", 'w'), level=logging.INFO).start()

        super(MySpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)
```

Comment: ok thanks but do you know whether changing the setting in the `custom_settings` is supposed to work the way I wrote it?